# JQuery Document Ready - Multiple allowed?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery - is it bad to have multiple $(document).ready(function() {});](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1148241/jquery-is-it-bad-to-have-multiple-document-readyfunction)
>   [Can you have multiple $(document).ready(function() sections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327756/can-you-have-multiple-document-readyfunction-sections)

I would like to know if it's allowed to have multiple instances of:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

})
```

on one of several pages ?

Comment: It's allowed, you can use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Not a problem to do that.

Just to extend on that: http://jsfiddle.net/CBCrZ/

Answer (score 2):

not sure what you mean by on several pages. But yes you can have multiples of document.ready. They will get called in the order you add them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use it more than once. see this post

[http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Multiple_$(document).ready()](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMultiple_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Is fine to have more than one. The call order is the same as the definition order: first-come first-served.

See also here:
[second $(document).ready event jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759822/second-document-ready-event-jquery)